# Trying to get my data in a form that makes it easy to do time series

Tags: r, dataframe, glm, lm

I've got four datasets I've pulled down from a public database. Each is in xls or xlsx format. I've gone through and converted them into data frames, and cleaned up the data from two previous years that had many extraneous fields. Now all of the data is in the same format, I'm trying to figure out how to process it into one document so I can do linear models over time for rate or proportion of growth.

Here is my GitHub link to my actual current process. If you feel like looking at it and offering advice, I would be greatly indebted.
https://github.com/benjaminmbaker/Data

Here is how I've been able to replicate a near facsimile of how my data is currently formatted:

```
x <- list()
years <- c(2006,2008,2010,2012)

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
    UniqueID <- 1:10 # <- Not all numeric - Kept as character vector
    Name <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
    Entity_Type <- factor("This","That")
    Data1 <- rnorm(10)     
    Data2 <- rnorm(10) 
    Data3 <- rnorm(10) 
    Data4 <- rnorm(10) 
    Year <- years[i]
    x[[i]] <- data.frame(UniqueID, Name, Entity_Type, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Year)
}

list2env(setNames(x, paste0('x', years)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Now that I have four datasets, I rbind them so that they are all in the same set so I can do OLS or GLM on the rate and proportion. Due to the number of 0's in my dataset created by the code in GitHub, I'm also looking at creating a dummy variable for values above zero, and then just running these functions on that.

```
rbind(x2006,x2008,x2010,x2012)
```

I'm quite new to this, so I know I'm making a lot of mistakes. I'll keep reading and working at this but any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use years[i] to paste in the value you want in the loop from the object. This will give you what you want:

```
my_df <- data.frame() # make an empty data frame to fill 
years <- c(2006,2008,2010,2012)

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
    UniqueID <- 1:10
    Name <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
    Entity_Type <- rep(c("This","That"), times=5) # do you want these to alternate?
    Data1 <- rnorm(10)     
    Data2 <- rnorm(10) 
    Data3 <- rnorm(10) 
    Data4 <- rnorm(10) 
    Year <- years[i]
    temp_df <- data.frame(UniqueID, Name, Entity_Type, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Year)
    my_df <- rbind(my_df, temp_df) 
}

my_df
```